# Instantiating multiple beans of the same class with Spring annotations

Tags: spring, annotations

With an XML configured Spring bean factory, I can easily instantiate multiple instances of the same class with different parameters. How can I do the same with annotations? I would like something like this:

```
@Component(firstName="joe", lastName="smith")
@Component(firstName="mary", lastName="Williams")
public class Person { /* blah blah */ }
```

Comment: I don't think you can. `@Component` is a lightweight convenience, but no substitute for XML config.

Comment: I think it is regrettable that XML is considered the proper way to configure an application.

Comment: Just because `@Component` can't do it doesn't mean XML is the solution.  I don't know about 2011, but you can achieve the same effect in a java `@Configuration` just fine now.

Comment: @apottere Can you post an answer? If you mean exactly what Espen says in his answer, it is not really an answer to this particular question. It is only close..

Comment: @KorayTugay that's exactly what I meant.  How is it not an answer to this question?  XML is no longer the proper way to configure an application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a help of your custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor implementation.

Here is a simple example.

Suppose we have two components. One is dependency for another.

First component:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

 public class MyFirstComponent implements InitializingBean{

    private MySecondComponent asd;

    private MySecondComponent qwe;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(asd);
        Assert.notNull(qwe);
    }

    public void setAsd(MySecondComponent asd) {
        this.asd = asd;
    }

    public void setQwe(MySecondComponent qwe) {
        this.qwe = qwe;
    }
}
```

As you could see, there is nothing special about this component. It has dependency on two different instances of MySecondComponent.

Second component:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;


@Qualifier(value = "qwe, asd")
public class MySecondComponent implements FactoryBean {

    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        return new MySecondComponent();
    }

    public Class getObjectType() {
        return MySecondComponent.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It's a bit more tricky. Here are two things to explain. First one - @Qualifier - annotation which contains names of MySecondComponent beans. It's a standard one, but you are free to implement your own. You'll see a bit later why.

Second thing to mention is FactoryBean implementation. If bean implements this interface, it's intended to create some other instances. In our case it creates instances with MySecondComponent type.

The trickiest part is BeanFactoryPostProcessor implementation:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;


public class MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
        Map<String, Object> map =  configurableListableBeanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(Qualifier.class);
        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
            createInstances(configurableListableBeanFactory, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

    }

    private void createInstances(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory,
            String beanName,
            Object bean){
        Qualifier qualifier = bean.getClass().getAnnotation(Qualifier.class);
        for(String name : extractNames(qualifier)){
            Object newBean = configurableListableBeanFactory.getBean(beanName);
            configurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(name.trim(), newBean);
        }
    }

    private String[] extractNames(Qualifier qualifier){
        return qualifier.value().split(",");
    }
}
```

What does it do? It goes through all beans annotated with @Qualifier, extract names from the annotation and then manually creates beans of this type with specified names.

Here is a Spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="MySecondComponent"/>


    <bean name="test" class="MyFirstComponent">
        <property name="asd" ref="asd"/>
        <property name="qwe" ref="qwe"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Last thing to notice here is although you **can** do it you **shouldn't** unless it is a must, because this is a not really natural way of configuration. If you have more than one instance of class, it's better to stick with XML configuration.

Comment: Shouldn't `isSingleton` return `false`?

Comment: None of the beans this creates will get post-processed, presumably because the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` runs before any `BeanPostProcessor`s have been created. The documentation also says not to instantiate any beans (e.g. `getBeansWithAnnotation`) during `postProcessBeanFactory`.

Comment: I worked out how to avoid some of those problems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41489377/476716

Comment: But you still ended up use XML. I actually prefer XML but came here to see if it is viable to go full annotation based. But if I still have to create XML and also create Factories etc then why not simply use XML all the way?

Answer (score 38):

It's not possible. You get a duplicate exception.

It's also far from optimal with configuration data like this in your implementation classes.

If you want to use annotations, you can configure your class with [Java config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java):

```
@Configuration
public class PersonConfig {

    @Bean
    public Person personOne() {
        return new Person("Joe", "Smith");
    }

    @Bean
    public Person personTwo() {
        return new Person("Mary", "Williams");
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're using a separate factory for each different Spring bean you create. I believe he wants the annotation configuration to be in the Person class. And I can only see one annotation in your relatively advanced example and that annotation doesn't support several different beans. But I'm impressed of the complexity of your solution though :-)

Comment: how do you use Joe value from a property file?

Comment: This is the exact equivalent of XML, the simplest solution possible.

Comment: this works, maybe  a builder rather than new would improve the quality of code, just my opinion

Answer (score 9):

I just had to solve a similar case. This may work if you can redefine the class.

```
// This is not a @Component
public class Person {

}

@Component
public PersonOne extends Person {
   public PersonOne() {
       super("Joe", "Smith");
   }
}

@Component
public PersonTwo extends Person {
   public PersonTwo() {
    super("Mary","Williams");
   }
}
```

Then just use PersonOne or PersonTwo whenever you need to autowire  a specific instance, everywhere else just use Person.

Comment: This is plain Java approach - much more Spring-like and less code would be using Spring @Qualifier annotations.

Comment: @Pavel But it is weird because I want instances of the same class, not classes representing individual instances (which is the case here...)

Comment: This doesn't answer to the question, he wants to have 2 instances of the same classes but having different attributes

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [wax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2903373/476716), the implementation can be safer and not skip other post-processing if definitions are added, not constructed singletons:

```
public interface MultiBeanFactory<T> {  // N.B. should not implement FactoryBean
  T getObject(String name) throws Exception;
  Class<?> getObjectType();
  Collection<String> getNames();
}

public class MultiBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
    Map<String, MultiBeanFactory> factories = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(MultiBeanFactory.class);

    for (Map.Entry<String, MultiBeanFactory> entry : factories.entrySet()) {
      MultiBeanFactory factoryBean = entry.getValue();
      for (String name : factoryBean.getNames()) {
        BeanDefinition definition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
            .genericBeanDefinition(factoryBean.getObjectType())
            .setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
            .setFactoryMethod("getObject")
            .addConstructorArgValue(name)
            .getBeanDefinition();
        definition.setFactoryBeanName(entry.getKey());
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(entry.getKey() + "_" + name, definition);
      }
    }
  }
}

@Configuration
public class Config {
  @Bean
  public static MultiBeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
    return new MultiBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  public MultiBeanFactory<Person> personFactory() {
    return new MultiBeanFactory<Person>() {
      public Person getObject(String name) throws Exception {
        // ...
      }
      public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return Person.class;
      }
      public Collection<String> getNames() {
        return Arrays.asList("Joe Smith", "Mary Williams");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

The bean names could still come from anywhere, such as wax's `@Qualifier` example. There are various other properties on the bean definition, including the ability to inherit from the factory itself.

Comment: This is cool. I hesitate to violate the Spring lifecycle constraint on `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` types by generating beans in the bean factory post processor phase. Although the beans generated here only have the intention of changing bean definitions (which, on its own, _should_ be safe during this phase), it is important to know that any other beans required by the `@Configuration` class may also be instantiated. This can lead to problems since the lifecycle constraints are violated. As long as this is well-documented, understood, and changes are reviewed carefully, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing @espen answer, injecting beans with qualifiers and configuring them differently with external values.

```
public class Person{
  @Configuration
  public static class PersonConfig{
    @Bean
    //@Qualifier("personOne") - doesn't work - bean qualifier is method name
    public Person personOne() {
        return new Person("Joe", "Smith");
    }

    @Bean
    //@Qualifier("personTwo") - doesn't work - bean qualifier is method name
    public Person personTwo(@Value("${myapp.second.lastName}") String lastName) {
        return new Person("Mary", lastName);
    }
  }
  /* blah blah */
}

@Component
public class SomePersonReference{
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("personTwo")
  Person marry;
}
```

Comment: If you name the variable to exactly match the method name, then I don't think you even need the @Qualifier annotation....
EG: 
```@Autowired
Person personTwo;```

Answer (score 1):

Should you need to inject, in the new created object, beans or properties from the spring context, you can have a look at the following section of code in which I have extended the [Espen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902965/379173)  by injecting a bean which is created from the spring context:

```
@Configuration
public class PersonConfig {

@Autowired 
private OtherBean other;

@Bean
public Person personOne() {
    return new Person("Joe", "Smith", other);
    }
}
```

Have a look at this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/playing-sround-with-spring-bean-configuration) for all the possibile scenarios.