# Is it possible to use multiple @Qualifier annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a set of beans that are characterized by two properties. They are basically serializers for different classes and for different purposes.

For example, there may be an `Order` serializer for local log, `Order` serializer for logging webservice call, `Customer` serializer for tracking URL and `Customer` serializer for tracking URL.

This is why I'd like to use two `@Qualifier` annotations like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("order")
@Qualifier("url")
private Serializer<Order> orderSerializer;
```

Unfortunately, compiler complains about duplicate annotations in this case. Are there any workarounds or alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: Even if you were allowed to use multiple annotations, there'd be no way to specify multiple qualifiers on the bean definitions themselves, so you'd be no further forward.

Comment: @skaffman It's possible, to be exact - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902335/instantiating-multiple-beans-of-the-same-class-with-spring-annotations , but of course I would not recommend that solution to use in production code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Qualifier("order-url")
```

and respectively name your component `order-url`

```
@Component("order-url")
```

Comment: This is what I've actually ended up doing, but it looks less clean that I'd like it to be.

Comment: If you use @Bean annotation in your Configuration, you could even give them multiple names like: @Bean({"b1", "b2"})
Might come in handy for testing stuff

Answer (score 14):

I understand that this question is rather old, but this is something you should be able to accomplish since Spring 2.5.

You can create your own annotations that are themselves annotated with `@Qualifier`, a form of annotation composition.  Spring will honor these qualifiers as though they are their own.

Consider these two annotation types, named similarly to your example:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface MyOrderQualifier {
}

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface MyUrlQualifier {
}
```

You should be able to use both of these annotations on your field, since they are independent annotations.

```
@Autowired
@MyOrderQualifier
@MyUrlQualifier
private Serializer<Order> orderSerializer;
```

Here is a link to the [Spring 2.5 reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) explaining this process.  Please note that it is for Spring 2.5 and may be out of date with regards to more recent versions of Spring.

Comment: this is the best solution so far

Comment: this will inject beans with MyOrderQualifier AND MyUrlQualifier,
is there a way we can inject beans with MyOrderQualifier OR MyUrlQualifier

Answer (score 0):

Of course I don't know all the details, but this issue is more like a task for [Decorator pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator). Probably, you may bound this in a Spring config if it's necessary.

Or, I agree with Bozho here, you could use some name conventions across you Spring beans, so that bean name could reflect its responsibility and area of application.

Comment: Could you explain how Decorator pattern can be used in this case?