# Spring Framework - Inject subset of beans

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired, tagging

I'm trying to control the dependency injection in spring so that only a subset of beans are injected by the `@Autowired` annotation, but I have yet to come across a solution that provides this behavior.

Imagine a scenario were there are many beans of a certain type, but you only want to use certain beans in various contexts. The `@Autowired` annotation supports bean collections, but it does not appear to have any support for applying restrictions to the various beans that could be injected (AFAIK).

```
@Autowired
Set<Foo> beansForContextA;

@Autowired
Set<Foo> beansForContextB;
```

The above code will inject the same set of beans into both `beansForContextA` and `beansForContextB`. I would like a way to distinguish what beans get injected into it's respective property. Is there something built into spring that supports this use case?

Consider the following pseudo code to illustrate the expectation more clearly:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean(tags = {"A"})
    Foo bean1() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean(tags = {"B"})
    Foo bean2() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean(tags = {"A", "B"})
    Foo bean3() {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class Impl {
    @Autowired(tags = {"A"})
    Set<Foo> beansForContextA;

    @Autowired(tags = {"B"})
    Set<Foo> beansForContextB;

    public void execute() {
        for (Foo foo : someCondition ? beansForContextA : beansForContextB) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here I would expect `beansForContextA` to have `bean1` and `bean3` and `beansForContextB` to have `bean2` and `bean3`. This can likely be achieved by extending the `@Autowired` and `@Bean` annotations to support "tags", but I'm curious if there is an already baked solution for this or will I have to invent my own?

Alternatively, is this even a good idea? Perhaps there is another approach that I have not come across yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [@Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) Annotation can achieve this. Out of the box, you can use a string to qualify beans and injection points:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("a")
Set<Foo> beansForContextA;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("b")
Set<Foo> beansForContextB;


@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("a")
    Foo bean1() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("b")
    Foo bean2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This won't work in your case however, as multiple instances of `@Qualifier` can't be present in the same place. [You have to create custom annotations which are annotated with `Qualifier` and use those instead of `@Qualifier` and a string name.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24024932/1503554)

```
@Target(value={FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,TYPE,ANNOTATION_TYPE})
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Inherited
 @Qualifier
public interface AScope

@Target(value={FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,TYPE,ANNOTATION_TYPE})
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Inherited
 @Qualifier
public interface BScope
```

With these custom annotations you'd end up with something like this.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    @AScope
    Foo bean1() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    @BScope
    Foo bean2() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    @AScope
    @BScope
    Foo bean3() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And at the injection point:

```
@Configuration
public class Impl {
    @Autowired
    @AScope
    Set<Foo> beansForContextA;

    @Autowired
    @BScope
    Set<Foo> beansForContextB;

    public void execute() {
        for (Foo foo : someCondition ? beansForContextA : beansForContextB) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. The information about `@Qualifier` will also be useful for simplified use-cases, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

another easy solution is using a new annotation.collect beans by spring and remove the not need beans by the new annotation.

```
public @interface BeanTag {
String value();
}
```

how to use.

```
@Bean
Foo bean1TypeA() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setType("typeA");
    return new Foo();
}
@Bean
Foo bean2TypeA() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setType("typeA");
    return new Foo();
}

@Bean
Foo bean1TypeB() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setType("typeB");
    return new Foo();
}

@Bean
Foo bean2TypeB() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setType("typeB");
    return new Foo();
}

@Autowired
@BeanTag("typeA")
private Set<Foo> collectionTypeA;

@Autowired
@BeanTag("typeB")
private Set<Foo> collectionTypeB;


@PostConstruct
public void removeNotNeedType(){
    // find all the field with @BeanTag remove not need bean

}
```

Comment: I like this solution, it's pretty straightforward. I would personally like to see an annotation only solution so that the annotation is not coupled to the type in any way and I don't need to have `@PostConstruct` implementations, but I upvoted nonetheless.