# how to create two instance of bean use anotate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

Assume I have a class `ResultService` and I want two instance of it. I can create

```
<beans>
 <bean id="result1" class="com.example.ResultService"/>
 <bean id="result2" class="com.example.ResultService"/>
<beans>
```

and use them like this:

```
@AutoWired @Qualifier("result1")
User result1;
@AutoWired @Qualifier("result2")
User result2;
```

but I wonder how can I create this with code and not xml configuration file

Comment: Define 2 `@Bean` annotated methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902965/1032167