# Spring Boot multiple JMS connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I'm developing Spring Boot application which must connect to several WebSphere JMS connections with different ports or even ip addresses. I need receive and send messages to different queues.

I took example of connection from this source - https://github.com/lzp4ever/IBM_WebSphere_MQ_Spring_Boot_JMS

But when i add second connectionFactory Spring Boot failes to start, it just don't know which once to use.

My question is How should i configure my config file to listen several queues? Is it good idea connecting SpringBoot app to several different JMS servers?

Comment: "fails to start" is not enough information; show the full error message, as well as all of your configuration. It is fine to have multiple connection factories but you need to wire everything together properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

i just copy and paste same beans(like at git link above) second time and add Bean(name) to separate them. It was not work and then i added new JmsListenerContainerFactory bean to each of my config file.

One of my config file is:

```
@Bean(name = "mqQueueConnectionFactory2")
public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory2() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
    try {
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("MQQueueConnectionFactory bean exception", e);
    }
    return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter2")
UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter2(@Qualifier("mqQueueConnectionFactory2") MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
    UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(username);
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(password);
    userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
    return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
}

@Bean(name = "cachingConnectionFactory2")
//@Primary
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory2(@Qualifier("userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter2") UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter) {
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(500);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "jmsTransactionManager2")
public PlatformTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager2(@Qualifier("cachingConnectionFactory2") CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
    JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
    jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
    return jmsTransactionManager;
}

@Bean(name = "jmsOperations2")
public JmsOperations jmsOperations2(@Qualifier("cachingConnectionFactory2") CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(receiveTimeout);
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory2(@Qualifier("cachingConnectionFactory2") CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                 DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}
```

---

Then i change my sender code from this:

```
@Autowired
private JmsOperations jmsOperations;
```

to this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jmsOperations2")
private JmsOperations jmsOperations;
```

---

also i change my receiver to:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${project.queues.uzb.recieve}", containerFactory = "myFactory2")
public void receiveMessage(JMSTextMessage data) {
    
}
```

it seems to me it worked!!!

But one of my CachingConnectionFactory must be marked as @Primary. If i delete @Primaty from one of my config files then i am gettig this error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2018-03-28 12:28:37 -

> ---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

> Description:

> Parameter 1 of method myFactory in com.config.UzbConnection required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' that could not be found.

> Action:

> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' in your configuration.

### Thanks

Comment: In my use case I was using an azure service bus and needed multiple topics, but would still encounter the need of @Primary. But found a way to solve it by removing service bus auto configuration by using @SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ServiceBusJmsAutoConfiguration::class]).

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents. If you have problems with multiple JMS connections because you have a project using a mix of Spring-boot and JMS with Spring xml configuration to make your connection factory, you can disable autostart of spring-boot-jms with this in your application:

```
 @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JmsAutoConfiguration.class})
```

this way you can mix both.