# Spring: How to create two distinct beans from the same class using annotations?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say we have the following class:

```
public class Service {
    private String name;

    public Service(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /// other methods
}
```

Let's say I want to generate two distinct beans from the same class. If I use xml, it's very easy:

```
<beans>
   <bean id="service1" class="Service">
      <constructor-arg value="first service" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="service2" class="Service">
      <constructor-arg value="second service" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

My question is how it can be generated using spring annotations.

Edit: 
The answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902335/instantiating-multiple-beans-of-the-same-class-with-spring-annotations) is not suitable to my question. In this link, the class MySecondComponent is generated twice, but it has a default constructor, and we don't pass different arguments/dependencies for each instantiation.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902965/438154) not answer your question?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis question's author has to use `@Bean` annotation with `name` attribute. Answer you mentioned is incomplete.

Comment: @KenBekov What? The annotated method's name will be used if `name` is not provided. The point is to use `@Bean` as the equivalent to `<bean>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you're right. I thought he needs few ID for any bean.

Comment: I opened a new question following the instruction "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, please see the note I added:
The answer in this link is not suitable to my question. In this link, the class MySecondComponent is generated twice, but it has a default constructor, and we don't pass different arguments/dependencies for each instantiation.

Comment: There's more than one answer in that question. The one I linked to in my previous comment does everything you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do the same in Java (Starting with spring 3.x):

```
@Configuration
public class MySampleConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public Service service1() {
      return new Service("first service");
   }

   @Bean
   public Service service2() {
      return new Service("second service");
   }
}
```

**Update 1**

Based on OP's comment:

There are different use cases, some require specifying bean names, other don't.

***Use case 1:***

Say, there is a bean that needs to be instantiated with, say `service1`:

```
public class SampleBean {
    private final Service service;

    public SampleBean(Service service) {
       this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Ideally you don't want to specify a qualifier in the code of `SampleBean` class because it kind of kills the dependency injection principle to some extent. However you can do it in configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MySampleConfigurationWithQualifier {

    @Bean(name = "service1")
    public Service service1() {
       return new Service1("first service");
    }

    @Bean(name = "service2")
    public Service service2() {
       return new Service2("second service");
    }

    @Bean
    public SampleBean sampleBean(@Qualifier("service1") Service service) {
       return new SampleBean(service);
    }
}
```

***Use case 2:***

Say, these services should be injected in some sort of collection (say, list) into another bean.

In this case, there is no need to specify `name` attribute

```
public class SampleBean2 {

   private final List<Service> services;

   public SampleBean2(List<Service> services) {
      this.services = services;
   }

   public void notifyOnSomeEvent(Event evt) {
      for(Service service : services) {
        service.notify(evt);
      }
   }
}
```

In this case the configuration could look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MySampleConfigurationWithListInjection {

    @Bean(name = "service1")
    public Service service1() {
       return new Service1("first service");
    }

    @Bean(name = "service2")
    public Service service2() {
       return new Service2("second service");
    }

    @Bean
    public SampleBean2 sampleBean2(List<Service> services) {
       return new SampleBean2(services);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to give a specific name to each one of these beans (e.g. @Bean(name="service1")). Let's say I need service1, how can I tell Spring that I want it?

Comment: I depends on what you actually need. Indeed if you want to inject service1, you should specify a name and Use @Qualifier. On the other hand, sometimes if you need to inject a list of services to another bean - you don't have to use names. There are different use cases. I'll update the answer with examples.