# Spring boot: Instantiating Spring java configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am converting a Spring legacy application based on XML to Spring Boot with java based configuration.
My question is, is it possible to instantiate same bean class with different bean names?
Example:

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {
   @Bean 
   public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
      return new HelloWorld();
   }
}
```

Can I have Spring boot instantiate above helloWorld bean using dynamically generated names like
helloWorld_1, helloWorld_2 etc in a loop? I want to control the naming of these beans. _1, _2 is something I will provide and these actually are IP Addresses.
All these beans are instances of same class HelloWorld.
Here is more context to what I am asking.
I am performing a distributed transactions on several data sources. These data sources can be anywhere from 2 to N. Now, I need to instantiate session factories, transaction managers and Dao impl classes one for each of these data sources. This is my usecase. I am not building a web application, but a console application. Just to be clear.
Really appreciate, if there is a way out for this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902335/instantiating-multiple-beans-of-the-same-class-with-spring-annotations